# scikit learn py-earth method parameter 'check_every' and 'min_search_point' doesn't work

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am using the method named py-earth from https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/py-earth.

I am trying to use the parameter `check_every` to control my fitting time, but I found it didn't make any differences when I change the init parameter `check_every`.

So I wonder whether the parameter `check_every` is useful now?

Answer (score 1):

Quoted from [github](https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/py-earth/issues/130#issuecomment-239050763):

> I think if you set check_every sufficiently high, you should eventually see a worse fit (and maybe a very slight speed up). I think it speaks to the usefulness of check_every that I actually had to look in the code to make sure it's even still implemented. All it does is reduce the number of candidate knot locations during knot search. One reason to do this would be to make sure you don't end up with knots too close together. However, the minspan argument takes care of that in a much nicer way.